# sed to remove lines starting with 'du`

Tags: sed, disk-usage

I intent to check the diskspace with `du -s`

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z /]# du -s /* | sort -k 1|sed "/du/d"
du: cannot access ‘/proc/31265/task/31265/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/31265/task/31265/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/31265/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/31265/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
0   /bin
0   /dev
0   /lib
0   /lib64
0   /proc
0   /sbin
0   /sys
158784  /boot
16  /lost+found
2458148 /usr
37500   /etc
496 /run
4   /home
4   /media
4   /mnt
4   /opt
4   /srv
534680  /root
568 /tmp
935544  /var
```

So I start to delete lines containing `du`

1, sed "/du/d"

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z /]# du -s /* | sort |sed "/du/d" | head -n 6
du: cannot access ‘/proc/31563/task/31563/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/31563/task/31563/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/31563/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/31563/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
0   /bin
0   /dev
0   /lib
0   /lib64
0   /proc
0   /sbin
```

2,Remove the lines not starting with number `sed "/[^\d]*/d"`

```
    [root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z /]# du -s /* | sort -k 1|sed "/[^\d]*/d" | head -n 6
    du: cannot access ‘/proc/31612/task/31612/fd/4’: No such file or directory
    du: cannot access ‘/proc/31612/task/31612/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
    du: cannot access ‘/proc/31612/fd/4’: No such file or directory
    du: cannot access ‘/proc/31612/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory

but return the lines I want to delete
```

3,sed "/\d*/d"

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z /]# du -s /* | sort -k 1|sed "/\d*/d" | head -n 6
du: cannot access ‘/proc/31703/task/31703/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/31703/task/31703/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/31703/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/31703/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
```

How could I remove the lines containing "du"?

Comment: The lines beginning with `du:` appear to be error messages; as such, you can suppress them by simply redirecting the error stream i.e. `du -s /* 2>/dev/null | sort -k 1` - there's no need for post-processing via `sed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As steeldriver commented, the lines beginning with `du: cannot access ...` and ending with `:No such file or directory` are error messages from du; it had enumerated those directories in /proc, but the corresponding process(es) had exited before `du` got around to summing their "disk" space, causing an error when it tried to access those now non-existent directories.

Thankfully, `du` emits those errors, as it should, to stderr, so you can intercept them and drop them with:

```
du -s /* 2>/dev/null | sort -n
```

I also changed your `sort` command, on the assumption that you want to sort numerically, with the largest sizes at the end.